# Qt5.12.1 QT_CONFIG(future) to broke when changing compiler from MinGW to MSVC

Tags: qt, qt5

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      QApplication a(argc, argv);
      MainWindow w;
      w.show();

      return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT

   public:
   explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
   ~MainWindow();

    private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    };

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

When compiling using MinGW 64bit, everything is OK.
Clear All project, switch compiler to MSVC2017 64 bit, QtCreator doesn't recognize any Qt Class starting with QApplication the first in main.cpp.
After investigation, I found in the **qmainwindow.h** : QT_CONFIG(future) causing division by zero in the preprocessor expression.
An example from **qmainwindow.h**:

```
#ifndef QDYNAMICMAINWINDOW_H
#define QDYNAMICMAINWINDOW_H 

#include <QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qwidget.h>
#if QT_CONFIG(tabwidget)    <-------- this line is grayed out and error is: division by zero in preprocessor expression. Warning is QT_FEATURE_tabwidget is not defined, evaluates to 0
#include <QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h>     <--------- this line is grayed out also
#endif
```

the **QT_CONFIG** is defined in **qglobal.h** as:

```
#define QT_CONFIG(feature) (1/QT_FEATURE_##feature == 1)  <--- this causes the /0.
```

but in **qtwidgets-config.h**:

```
#define QT_FEATURE_tablewidget 1
#define QT_FEATURE_tabwidget 1    <----------- tabwidget is defined as it should be (1 not 0)
#define QT_FEATURE_textbrowser 1
#define QT_FEATURE_toolbar 1
```

Above is an example for tabwidget, but QT_CONFIG causes division by zero for all other widgets which causes the application to never compile.

I created a new project from scratch and configured Kits to Desktop Qt 5.12.1 MSVC2017 64bit, got the same errors (without touching MinGW).

Comment: Something looks messed up with the MSVC Qt kit. No warning icons on that kit in QtCreator config? Have you tried re-installing the kit maybe? Which build system are you using? You may need to post the config for that also (project.pro or CMakeLists.txt). Usually switching between project kits "just works."

Comment: @Maxim Paperno -> You bring me to investigate in depth in this way. In fact, the PC were Qt is installed is Windows Server 2012 where Visual Studio 2017 is installed by the system admin while Qt is installed by non system admin account. When I switch to system admin account and launch Qt, all environment variables are set correctly, especially variables related to VS paths and Windows SDK paths (~ 6 or 7 env variables) and project buils on both MSVC and MinGW. When I return back to non amin account and launch Qt, all variables, VS paths and Windows SDK are either set to wrong values or not..

Comment: ... set at all, which causes MSVC to not find its includes dirs or libraries paths.